# Parsing with Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I'm desperate, I'm trying to parse a website (www.proyectoglass.com) with Android and Jsoup(1.7.2), seems that the code works well with other websites (like www.google.com) but when I try to parse that address the ListView is not showing anything.

```
static final String BLOG_URL = "http://www.proyectoglass.com/";
static final String TAG_titulo = "title";
ArrayList<String> copia=new ArrayList<String>();
 @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // set layout view
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        try {
            getTitles();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", "Obtaining values");
        }   
         ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,copia);
         listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

} 
protected void getTitles() throws IOException{

   Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();

    for (Element element : document.select("a")) {          

        if( element.hasText() )                 
        {
            System.out.println(element.text()); // print the element's text
            copia.add(element.text());
        }                   

    }   

}
```

someone have any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: `but not with the one that I have to parse.` - What about it does not work? Does it crash? Does it simply not return the data you are looking for? As it stands this question does not contain enough relevant information to be answerable.

Comment: Sorry, English is not my main language and I have the feeling that I didn't express myself correctly. I tried different websites (like www.google.com) and it works but I have to parse a specific website (www.projeyectoglass.com) and for some reason doesn't works.

Comment: I think it's simple, that page simply relies heavily on Javascript to create the dynamic layout and as such, you can't parse it with a HTML parser.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: the page you're trying to parse, doesn't have any a-tags, so you won't get any elements returned and hence nothing to add to your `ListView`.

Comment: You are right, my apologies, I was using Firebug to see the webpage code and was showing the code after process the webpage (this is embarrassing).